# Visual Studio - Selective skin files

Tags: html, visual-studio, skins

Is there something similar to a skin file in visual studio where the properties of the "skin" file are only applied if they do not exist in the tag. So, if I have a skin file:

```
<p class="myClass">
```

And two tags:

```
<p class="someClass">HelloWorld</p>
<p>HelloWorld</p>
```

I want the "skin" file to add the class "myClass" only to the second paragraph tag. Is this possible?

Comment: By "skin" do you simply mean CSS?

Comment: I mean, I have to use something in visual studio that adds the class, not in jquery, css, etc. A skin file in visual studio finds all specified tags and replaces their classes, attributes, etc by the ones specified in the skin file. I used the class just as an example.

Comment: Or in other words, the class has to be added before it is sent to the client.